# Do AMD loaders need a way to initiate module resolution other than "define?"

Tags: javascript, amd, loader

In a discussion about a tangentially related aspect of a minimal AMD loader I'm working on, James Burke wrote:

> There should to be some way to kick off the resolution of modules, besides just define(). define() calls by themselves should just register the existence of a module definition, but not immediately execute the factory function. That will more closely match expectations that people have from other loaders and how it more closely matches the behavior of dynamically loaded modules, whose factory functions are only called because they are part of a top level load dependency tree.

If anyone knows about AMD, this is the guy. However, I wonder if he may have been misunderstanding how my loader works. It doesn't immediately execute the factory, but it does immediately start resolving dependencies when `define` is called.

Essentially, my loader uses `define` for the same thing RequireJS uses global `require` for, which makes sense to me, given that the functions do very similar things and their signatures are nearly identical.

---

In a [new thread](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/amd-implement/-z-Umb-cz4o/discussion) on the [AMD implementers mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/amd-implement) I responded:

> The AMD loader I'm working on does not have a special way to kick off module resolution. The entire API is a global `define` function. When `define` is called, any dependencies are immediately loaded (if they haven't already started loading). When all dependencies in the chain are finished loading, the factory executes.
>
> This has been good enough for my purposes so far, but is there some caveat I'm missing? What are some reasons for having a separate function to initiate module resolution, rather than simply resolving dependencies as soon as they're encountered and running factories as soon as all dependencies are met?

---

That list doesn't get a lot of traffic, so I'm crossposting it here. I'd like to get some input from anyone who has been using an AMD loader regularly. Can you anticipate any problems with using `define` instead of a separate function to kick things off? I completely respect James's opinion on this, but I wonder if he's so used to the RequireJS way of doing things that anything else seems wrong, even if it works fine in practice.

Recap:

- When `define` is called, all dependencies in the list start loading (if not already started).
- When all dependencies are ready (have export values), the factory runs.
- That's the entire API, there is no global `require`.

What problems (if any) are there with this approach, other than not being immediately familiar to someone coming from RequireJS?

---

Update: There's been some activity on the [thread](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/amd-implement/-z-Umb-cz4o/discussion) where this originated. So far it's looking like this amounts to an eager-loading vs lazy-loading scenario. I still think eager loading could be a viable approach, but would like to get more input from others.

---

In response to the downvotes on this question: If the question can be improved, please let me know *how* it can be improved. I've been as clear as I possibly can; if there's something else that needs clarifying, or some other reason this question seems to be of low quality, please bring it to my attention and I will fix it.

Answer (score 3):

> What are some reasons for having a separate function to initiate module resolution, rather than simply resolving dependencies as soon as they're encountered and running factories as soon as all dependencies are met?

Yes, as already got mentioned on that thread it is for lazy loading. `define` does *register* a callback to to create a module, while `require` actually triggers the loads and creates the module instance.

AMD is built around this idea, but it doesn't necessitate it. [From the spec](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/blob/master/require.md#local-vs-global-require-):

> A global `require()` function is one that is available in the global
>   scope, like `define()`. An implementation **is not required to implement** a
>   global `require`, but if it does, the behavior of global `require` is
>   similar to the behavior of the local `require()` function, with the
>   following qualifications: […]
>
> There is often an implementation-dependent API that will kick off
>   module loading; if interoperability with several loaders is needed,
>   the global `require()` should be used to load the top level modules
>   instead.

Building an eager loader is fine and does conform to the spec.

Comment: It definitely does conform to the spec as written, but maybe not the *spirit* or the spec? At this point, I guess I'm worried about whether there could be any problems beyond the usual eager-vs-lazy concerns. Two people in those threads have mentioned build-time concatenation of scripts as being a potential issue. I don't see it as being an issue, so either I am misunderstanding them or they are misunderstanding me.

Comment: The implementation is more complicated, considering the case of a `define` that uses modules defined further below in the same script. A lazy loading script just builds the dependency map first and traverses it when a module is `require`d. But if you're doing everything correct™, I don't see any problems.

Comment: @Bergi Yeah that was going to be my comment.  If someone has concatenated several scripts so that a single script now has multiple `define` calls in it, it could be that the 2nd `define` call defines a dependency that the 1st `define` call needs.  Deferring execution until somone calls `require` will prevent an error from occurring when the 1st `define` finally tries to resolve its dependencies.

Comment: @Brandon deferring execution until dependencies are resolved also prevents this error. 1: first module has an unmet dependency on second module, so the factory doesn't execute yet. 2: second module defines the dependency the first module needed, and exports values when its dependencies are met. 3: first module's dependencies are now met, so the factory executes. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/WsE2G/ ... I feel like I've tried to explain that execution is deferred until dependencies are ready several times now, is there a way I can explain this better?

Comment: @DaggNabbit then when would you ever finally report that dependencies could not be satisfied if the dev never defined them all?  Seems like you would still need something like `require` to let the developer say "i'm done providing defines.  tell me what I am missing."

Comment: @Brandon: That could easily be done when all outstanding script have (failed to be) loaded and executed.

Comment: @Brandon, what Bergi said, plus there is nothing in the spec that requires anything like this to be reported. It's not mentioned at all, actually. My goal was to do just enough to comply with the non-optional parts of the spec and nothing else (one of the reasons for no require).

Answer (score 1):

In the AMD-loader that I wrote, I simply use the following (optional) definition of require():

```
function require(deps, callback) {
  define(1, deps, callback);
}
```

Due to an implementation detail in the [lockandload AMD-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lockandload) using `1` as the first argument to `define()` results in a functional equivalence with `require()`.

IOW: if people want a `require()` it's cheap to create once you have `define()`. I cannot imagine the difference being much larger in other loaders.  It also implies that there is no pressing need to pollute the global space with yet another function, unless you consider it improves readability of the code.